# Controlling which sitemap to display to the user without using Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitemap

I am running into a task where I have to hide some of the sitemap links. For example, in this sitemap menu:

> Restaurant
>
> > Review Resturant
> >
> > Add restaurant
>
> Event
>
> > Create Event
> >
> > Join Event
>
> Admin
>
> > Manage Users

The admin node should not be displayed to all users.

We are not using the normal MVC Role security model. What we have is an if statement at the start of every controller. It redirect the user to another page if the user does not have access. Here is an example:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string view)
    {
      if (dao.HasPermission(dao.screenLoanDialogue, dao.PermissionsFull) == false)
      return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Home");
      //rest of code here 
    }
```

How can I force the site map to not show the nodes that the user does not have access to? One of the solutions that I can try is passing all the mapsite to a controller and have it handle which nodes to display. But I could not find where the nodes are collected.

Roles and writing the page in HTML are out of options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating a class with a few methods to check access for you?

```
public static class LinkChecker 
{
    public static bool IsAdminLinkAllowed(User userOrWhatever)
    {
        // stuff here
    }
}
```

then in your view call this before rendering the link.

```
@if(LinkChecker.IsAdminLinkAllowed(user))
{
    @Html.ActionLink()
}
```

Alternatively, you could (and probably should) check for the access in your controller and pass the values to the view.

```
ViewBag.IsAdminLinkAllowed = LinkChecker.IsAdminLinkAllowed(user);
```

and in the view:

```
@if(ViewBag.IsAdminLinkAllowed)
{
    @Html.ActionLink()
}
```